# Mapper and several one to many relationships

Tags: scala, lift

I want to declare an entity which has several one-to-many relationships. Unfortunately, I have to implement OneToMany traits for each one to many relationship. I can't do this two times. Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a handy way to test this at the moment, but if I remember correctly you can have as many [`MappedOneToMany`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.mapper.OneToMany%24MappedOneToMany) objects as you need once you've mixed in `OneToMany`:

```
class User extends LongKeyedMapper[User] with IdPK with OneToMany[Long, User] {
  object pets extends MappedOneToMany(Pet, Pet.owner)
  object books extends MappedOneToMany(Book, Book.owner)
}
```

Note that `OneToMany` doesn't have a type parameter for the related table.

Comment: Thanks. I mixed source table with a target table.